# Contagem de diárias - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Bom dia!
No exemplo enviado temos um numero de atendimento, a data de entrada e a data de saída do paciente; e a contagem das diárias. Na contagem das diárias estou considerando apenas o período de 01/07/2017 à 31/07/2017, contando inclusive o primeiro dia. Ou seja, na linha 1 estou contando os dias a partir de 01/07 até 16/07, o que me retorna 16 dias. Até aí, ok. O problema é que na linha dois o paciente teve uma mudança de setor, ficando nesse novo setor até o dia 29/07.
É nesse ponto que preciso de uma ajuda. Como a contagem da linha 1 já considera o dia 16/07, na linha 2 eu precisaria que a data de entrada fosse contada somente a partir do dia 17/07. O campo DT_ENTR_AJUSTE foi criado na query já para tentar resolver esse problema, porém ainda está trazendo o dia 16/07, quando precisaria trazer o dia 17/07. 
O que preciso é, verificar se a data (hh/mm/ss) de saída da linha 1 for exatamente igual a data (hh/mm/ss) de entrada da linha 2 (no mesmo numero de atendimento), o campo DT_ENTR_AJUSTE deverá ser preenchido com +24h. Porém não estou conseguindo chegar nesse resultado.
Caso precisem da query, envio depois.

[image: resultado da query]

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer... 
Você quer verificar se quando a dt_entrada for igual a dt_saida anterior adicionar + 24hrs?

Comment: Olá André! Isso mesmo, quando a data de saída da linha 1 for igual a data de entrada da linha 2, preencher o campo  DT_ENTR_AJUSTE da linha 2 com 24hs a mais. exemplo: a data de saída da linha 1 = 16/07/2017 10:55:46, que é exatamente igual a data de entrada da linha 2, então a DT_ENTR_AJUSTE da linha 2 deverá ser preenchida com 17/07/2017 10:55:46.

Comment: Entendi... se você tiver como esperar, ao meio dia eu lhe ajudo com isso. Pode ser?

Comment: Claro, obrigada!

Comment: @AndréFilipe, não existe necessidade alguma de um dump com um exemplo simples deste, este seu requerimento soa como algo muito mal intencionado.

Answer (score 0):

É possível utilizar a função analítica [Lead](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm), possibilitando acessar valores de diferentes rows. Excemplo:

```
select e.dt_entrada,
       decode(lead (dt_saida,1)  over ( ORDER BY dt_entrada desc), e.dt_entrada, dt_ajuste+1, dt_ajuste) as dt_ajuste,
       e.dt_saida
    from exemplo e
 order by dt_entrada
```

No exemplo esta verificando a dt_saida de um registro a frente, considerando a ordem dt_entrada decrescente, se o valor retornado for o mesmo da dt_entrada atual, ele incrementa 1 dia, caso contrário, retorna o valor atual.

exemplo no sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7503df9/1/0